# How to fetch modified object / specific date added objects using AWS PHP API V3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-php-sdk

I am trying to fetch the objects of the AWS S3 bucket using PHP AWS API V3 (ListObjectsV2). I am not able to find any perfect source or documentation to filter the result by specific date or other values.

I want to create a script for fetch daily updated objects to our database and server using PHP SDK.

```
$command = $s3->getCommand('ListObjectsV2');
$command['Bucket'] = 'TestBucket';
$command['MaxKeys'] = 10;
$date = '2020-04-30';
$command['Query'] = "Contents[?LastModified.date>='${date}']";
$objects = $s3->execute($command);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved my goal by putting below condition with search

```
$serach_expression = "Contents[?(contains(Key, '.jpg') || contains(Key, '.jpeg') && LastModified[?date>=2020-05-01])].{Key: Key, Size: Size, LastModified: LastModified}";

$items = $objectInfo->search($serach_expression);
```